# Root of a plynomial in (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, fixed-point-theorems, binomial-distribution

Define $$f_K(x)=\sum_{i=K+1}^{2K} \binom{2K}{i}x^{i-1}(1-x)^{2K-i}.$$ How to show that $qf_K(x)-f_K(1-x)$ has exactly one real root in $(0,1)$ for any $q > 0$ and $K \geq 1$. The proof for $q=1$ goes as follows:

\begin{align}
f_k(x)-f_K(1-x)&= \sum_{i=K+1}^{2K} \binom{2K}{i}\left[x^{i-1}(1-x)^{2K-i}-(1-x)^{i-1}x^{2K-i}\right]\\
               &= \sum_{i=K+1}^{2K} \binom{2K}{i} x^{2K-i}(1-x)^{2K-i}\left[x^{2(i-K)-1}-(1-x)^{2(i-K)-1}\right]\\
               &= (2x-1)\sum_{i=K+1}^{2K} \binom{2K}{i}x^{2K-i}(1-x)^{2K-i} \sum_{r=0}^{2(i-K)-2} x^r (1-x)^{2(i-K)-2-r}
\end{align}

Clearly, the above expression is $>0$ if $x > 1/2$, $<0$ if $x < 1/2$, and zero at $x=1/2$. So it has a unique root at $x=1/2$. But this argument does not generalize for other values of $q$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L\left(x\right):=q\cdot f_{K}\left(x\right)-f_{K}\left(1-x\right)$.
We have $L\left(0\right)=-1<0$ and $L\left(1\right)=q>0$, so by
continuity, $L\left(x\right)=0$ has at least one solution (existence).
Towards uniqueness, you have shown that there exists a unique $x$
such that $f_{K}\left(x\right)-f_{K}\left(1-x\right)=0$, so we write
$L\left(x\right)=\left(q-1\right)\cdot f_{K}\left(x\right)$. Show
that has a unique maximum $x^{*}$ by taking the derivative wrt $x$.
Show then that $L\left(x^{*}\right)>0.$ Since $L\left(0\right)<0$,
$L\left(x^{*}\right)>0$ and $L\left(\cdot\right)$ is strictly increasing
in $\left[0,x^{*}\right]$ we have that it has a unique solution in
that interval.